# what does it mean for a single variable to be uncorrelated?

Tags: correlation, random-variable

In the simple linear regression model, y=a+bx+e, e is assumed to be uncorrelated. Accordingly, y is uncorrelated.  I understand that two variables are uncorrelated if their covariance is zero.  But what does it mean for a single variable to be uncorrelated?

EDIT in response to Glen_b's comment below: (i've learned some mathjax now)

From Montgomery, Peck, and Vining, 5th ed:

> quotes from page 12
>
> *The simple linear regression model is $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$*
>
> *... $\epsilon$ is a random error component*
>
> *... We usually assume that the errors are uncorrelated*

and

> quote from page 13
>
> *... because the errors are uncorrelated, the responses are uncorrelated.*

Comment: The usual assumption is that e and x are uncorrelated.

Comment: But $y$, $x$ and $e$ are not single variables. Presumably the intent is that $e_i$ is uncorrelated with $e_j$ for $j\neq i$. Please give an exact quote or reference so we can make sure what the actual intent is.

Comment: Thanks, I've added quotes into the Q.  Perhaps my terminology is wrong. Are not each of $y, x, \epsilon$ single variables? Maybe this is reveals a fundamental misconception on my part.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to what is meant by something like this:

$y_i = a + bx_i + \epsilon_i$, where we assume $\epsilon_i$ is iid (and thus uncorrelated).

In such a model, we have several instances, i.e. $i \in 1, ..., n$. When it is said that $\epsilon_i$ is iid, it means that *all of the $\epsilon_i$'s are independent of each other*. In other words, $\epsilon_1$ is independent of $\epsilon_2$, $\epsilon_3$, etc.

Comment: here is an example: in the derivation of Var[b], Var distributes across the summation "because the observations y are uncorrelated" (quote is from my textbook).

Comment: right. So they are saying $y_1$, $y_2$, .... are all uncorrelated.

Comment: which is my original question, what does it mean for a single variable to be uncorrelated?  Is there a calculation that can be made?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Correlation describes the relation between two different variables. It makes sense to say $y_1$ is uncorrelated with $y_2$. But if you had only one observation, (i.e. $n = 1$), the statement about being uncorrelated is now meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we could use an example, assume that you want to determine the weight of people when you know their length and, to simplify, assume it is linear, i.e. $w =\beta_0 + \beta_1 l + \epsilon$.

Obviously, if you take all people with a same length of 1.8 meter, they will not have the same weight. Assume that, for all people of length $l=1.8$, the weights of all these people show a normal distribution, i.e the distribution of weight given the length is normal: $w|_l \sim N(\mu_l, \sigma)$.

What linear regression assumes is the $\mu_l = \beta_0 + \beta_1 l$, so $w|_l \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1 l, \sigma)$ so for each value of the length, you find a normal distribution of weights, with mean dependent on the length.

The assumption is that these weights (the $y$ are the weights in this case) are all independent so (a) if I take persons with the same length, they can have different weights (coming from a normal distribution) but their weights are independent of each other, so if I know the weight of the one, it does not tell me anything about the weight of the other and (b) is I take two persons with a different length then their weights come from two different normal distributions but these weights are also independent.

Comment: I'd disagree.  Knowing nothing else, the weight of person A is a better estimate of the weight of person B (particularly if they are the same height), than choosing a number at random from the positive real line.  If one knows the range of human weights, then using weight of A as an estimate of the weight of B is at least as good as picking a random number from the range.

Comment: Consider a finite population of objects with finite weights.  Given that the population is finite and that the weights are finite, their weights fall in finite range. Given just that, what is object A's weight?  Could be any number on the positive real line.  Now suppose the weight of object A is known.  One then knows that the range of weights includes the weight of A.  Using the weight of A as an estimate of the weight of object B guarantees that the estimate is withing the range, which is an infinitely better estimate, literally, than choosing a number at random from the positive real line.

Comment: Therefore, for a finite population of finite weights, knowing the weight of one object always tells one something about the weight of other object.

Comment: @cwakers: well you can agree or disagree but (1) with the example I tried to explain what independence assumption means: if the observations are independent then it means that the weight of one does not influence the weight of the other and (2) if two persons have the same length, then they come from the same normal distribution, so in that sense, knowing the weight from one of the two, you know the normal distribution from which the weight of the other one is drawn that is right.

Comment: @cwackers: For your example: the weight of A does not tell anything about the weight of B. The only thing that you know is that for a child of 1m, the weight is drawn from $N(\beta_0+\beta_1;\sigma)$ and for a basketball player of 2.1m the weight is drawn from $N(\beta_0+2.1 \times \beta_1;\sigma)$, but knowing the value of a particular child, it will tell you nothing about which value from $N(\beta_0+2.1 \times \beta_1;\sigma)$ is the weight of the basketball player

Comment: @cwackers: let's take this as an example;  you know your weight and your length.  I tell you that my length is 1.79m, now you may, with only these data, estimate my weight.  Want to give it a try ? Do you think it will be an 'estimate' ? or a random guess ? or will it be 'between 0 and $+\infty$' ?

Comment: In English we normally talk about people's height, not length. (But we say someone is tall, not high.)

Comment: @Richard Hardy: I am not a native English speaker as you noticed, but apparently you understood :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Cliff AB is right, but I would like to add something

In a cross section we don't really (usually at least) think about the correlation within the error term itself - you do in time series and panal analysis.

Uncorrelated errors, in regression, can a mean a couple of thing. But the one the comes to mind is the (perhaps) most important assumption in linear regression. Namely the relationship between the error term and X-variables. For consistent estimates of the parameters, you need the assumption of no correlation between the x and the error term, that is: $E(e'x)=0$. This is almost always violated in terms of omitted variables, unless you have actual experimental data (or using simulated data, i.e. a computer experiment).

EDIT:

To actually adress your question; consider that:

$$
\text{Cov}(x,x) = \text{Var}(x)
$$

Therefore we can write:

$$
\rho_{(x,x)}= \frac{\text{Var}(x)}{\text{sd}(x) \cdot \text{sd}(x)} = 1
$$

Given that $\text{Var}(x) \neq 0$, which is not really an assumption. So to state that a single variable is uncorrelated, does not really make sense. In a regression context we think of uncorrelated errors like above, or across time (for time series and/or panel data applications). The are many exelent post on CV that descibes this.

Comment: here is an example from my textbook (p19, 5th ed, Montgomery, Peck Vining): in the derivation of Var[b], Var distributes across the summation "because the observations y are uncorrelated".  Earlier in the book (p13): "the responses are uncorrelated" because "the errors are uncorrelated".

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by e-prime x ... oh, maybe the dot product of e and x?

Comment: Yes the product of the transpose of e and x. Such that the correlation is 0 (the vectors are orthogonal). As per the other comment, it means that my outcome y (for instance my height) is uncorrelated with yours. They do not depend on each other. The is typical, and usually innocent, assumption in a cross section.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems needless to point out that the authors did not use the term dependent, or independent. Rather, they used the term uncorrelated, which of course is quite different in statistics. Since I am still not understanding, let me rephrase it this way: Given a dataset, what mathematics does one use to assess the correlation of the response variable?

Comment: I think that @fcop provided a neat example.